# error :id is already registered

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting

i have this error in my code

```
Error: Tried to register widget with id==legend1 but that id is already registered
```

the code for the legend is:

```
    <div id="legend1"></div>

    var stackedAreaLegend = new dojox.charting.widget.SelectableLegend({
    chart: chart1
    }, "legend1");   

   stackedAreaLegend.refresh();
```

how i can solve this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to destroy widget before creating new:

```
var stackedAreaLegend = dijit.byId('legend1');
if (stackedAreaLegend) {
   stackedAreaLegend.destroyRecursive(true);
}

stackedAreaLegend = new dojox.charting.widget.SelectableLegend({
    chart: chart1
    }, "legend1");   

stackedAreaLegend.refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat odd but it appears from looking at the example that it needs to happen at onLoad instead of when the DOM full loads. Try this in the head section of your HTML:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
  var stackedAreaLegend = dojox.charting.widget.SelectableLegend({chart: chart},"legend1");
  stackedAreaLegend.refresh();
});
```

Source: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/browser/dojox/trunk/charting/tests/test_selectableLegend.html?rev=23507

Comment: thanks. I have  dojo.addOnLoad(makeObjects); where makeObjects made the chart and the refresh. my problem is that the only thing that is really updated is the tool-tip. The updated chart is draw bellow of the correct div and the legend disappears

Answer (score 1):

I too got the same issue, this helped me

`var gridRegister = registry.byId('grid');
                   if (gridRegister) {
                   gridRegister.destroyRecursive(true);
                            }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:-

Aftter addSeries you can write:-

```
var legend = new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({ chart: chart, horizontal: false }, chartID);
```

And while updating that after `UpdatinSeries()` you can write :

```
dijit.byId(chartID + "_Legend").refresh();
```

For using digit you have to include:

```
dojo.require("dijit.registry");
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of it you should configure dojo loader in the header of the page with parseOnLoad: true parameter:

```
<script src="//yandex.st/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
```